# Jsch Shell won't accept input from Terminal

Tags: java, shell, groovy, ssh, terminal

I have written a simple groovy program that uses the Jsch Library to establish an ssh tunnel and open a shell on the target server. The script connect fine and the shell opens. In IntelliJ I can enter input into the shell and get the subsequent output if I run the program. However if I attempt to do the same in the Terminal or in a cmd it connects fine but I cannot enter any input so can't run commands.

```
println "Opening connection to ${sshUser}@${sshHost}:${sshPort}"
Properties config = new Properties()
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no")
JSch jsch = new JSch()

Session sshSession = jsch.getSession(sshUser, sshHost, sshPort as int)
sshSession.setPassword(sshPass)
sshSession.setConfig(config)
sshSession.connect()
println "Connected"


println "Forwarding connection to ${targetHost}:${targetPort}"
def assignedPort = sshSession.setPortForwardingL(0, targetHost, targetPort as int)
println "Got port $assignedPort"

// Set the session to open as a Shell
Channel channel = targetSession.openChannel("shell")
// Set Input and Output streams
channel.setInputStream(System.in)
channel.setOutputStream(System.out);
// Connect
channel.connect()
```

UPDATE

After further reading it seems that to get this working there is a hack for the Windows prompt. However the code that JCraft provided has a number of issues that I'm struggling with:

```
channel.setInputStream(new FilterInputStream(System.in){
      public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len)throws IOException{
        return in.read(b, off, (len>1024?1024:len));
      }
    });
```

I get the very helpful error "Wrong Statement"

Comment: I'm guessing you want to do this in a separate thread

Comment: Yes that's what I was hoping to do

Comment: Try calling `channel.setPty(true)` before calling `connect()`. You may be opening a raw pipe to the remote system which isn't responding to keystrokes the way you expect it to. If this doesn't help, please describe in detail how you're testing the connectivity to the remote system.

Comment: `setPty` isn't recognized as a method of channel? When I run the program using the IntelliJ it connects perfectly, accepting the input and outputting the results in a Linux style terminal. When I run using a cmd it still connects but I simply cannot type anything despite getting the same Linux style prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution really simple in the end. The Windows Prompt hack does work but needs to be tweaked as follows:

```
return System.in.read(b, off, (len>1024?1024:len));
```

Thanks for your help anyway guys